# simple draggable popup window with html5

Tags: jquery, html, popup, draggable

i'm trying to create a draggable popup. does anyone have any useful links or tutorials? i'd like to use html5 and no jquery and want to do this as simply and quickly as possible, no external libraries/ jquery ui etc. I have a div which looks like a popup, it's absolutely positioned, i now need to make it draggable....thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/) and [this](http://jsbin.com/uzovu) helpful.  Also Mozilla's developer [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations) has some info for HTML5 draggable.